# Call constructor with other class constant value

Tags: c#, .net-4.6

I want a constructor call to only allow a limited range of "extensions". Let's say I have these 2 classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Extension ext) 
    { 
        // do something
    }
}

public class Extension
{
    public const string TXT = ".txt";
    public const string XML = ".xml";
}
```

So, when another developer would want to use `Foo` he can only do so with the values from the `Extension` class like so:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Extension.TXT);
```

But when trying to do this I get an IDE error saying: `"cannot convert from 'string' to '<ProjectName>.Extension'`.

As a "workaround" I could change my `Extension` class to something like this:

```
public class Extension
{
    public enum File
    {
        TXT,
        XML
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Extension.File.TXT);
```

which works perfectly fine but what I do not like is that the call is one level longer (class -> enum -> element instead of class -> element).

So, the questions is is my workaround actually the only valid, correct or best practice solution?

Comment: Remove the num from the class and make it public. You will call only the enum: `new Foo(File.Txt);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a *Java style enum* class

```
public class Extension
{
    string _Extension = null;

    private Extension(string ext)
    {
        _Extension = ext;
    }

    public static Extension TXT 
    {
        get {  return new Extension(".txt"); }
    }

    public static Extension XML
    {
        get { return new Extension(".xml"); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _Extension;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var e = obj as Extension;
        if (e == null) return false;

        return e._Extension == this._Extension;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _Extension.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first example has `Extension` being used as a class with a couple of string constants. The second example uses an enum in lieu of the constants.

```
public class Foo
{
    // this .ctor expects a type of Extension, not a string.
    public Foo(Extension ext) 
    { 
        // do something
    }
}

// This class has only constant string values.
public class Extension
{
    public const string TXT = ".txt";
    public const string XML = ".xml";
}
```

Attempting to pass in a string to the above .ctor will not work as it is expecting a type of `Extension`, not a string.

```
// this passes in a string, not a type.
Foo foo = new Foo(Extension.TXT);
```

As you are wanting to limit the values available to the `Foo` .ctor, then use an enum as you have in your 2nd example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(File ext) 
    { 
        // do something
    }
}

public enum File
{
    TXT,
    XML
}
```

Then this will work as expected:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(File.TXT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to declare enum outside of class Foo and without any special class like extension?

```
public enum Extension
{
    TXT,
    XML
}

public class Foo 
{
    public Foo(Extension ext) 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then when you are constructing a Foo object you can simply do:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Extension.TXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a default constructor and implicit operator for string to Extension. Eg. something like:

```
public class Extension
{
    public const string TXT = ".txt";
    public const string XML = ".xml";

    private _value;
    public Extension(string value){if(value == TXT || value == XML) _value = value; else throw new NotImplementedException();}
    public static implicit operator string(Extension value){return _value;}
    public static implicit operator Extension(string value){if(value == TXT || value == XML) _value = value; else throw new NotImplementedException();}
}
```

that way you could call Foo(".txt") or Foo(Extension.TXT)

or you could define TXT as an instance of Extension:

```
public class Extension
{
    public const Extension TXT = new Extension(".txt");
    public const Extension XML = new Extension(".xml");

    public Value{get;private set;}
    public Extension(string value){Value = value;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first declaration of Extesion from Class to Enum